# How to make a quick backup of DB and restore it to previous version?

Tags: sql-server

If I want to test my DB against my software, can I just copy DB and log files and after tests just restore previous files?

Is it going to work and DB will be safe?
DB is currently offline and without clients but I don't want to breake it and I need a fast way to restore original version.

Unfortunately I cannot create another DB. So I can work only on this single one.

Answer (score 0):

A Backup is a copy of a database at the moment it was taken. You would need to do a Full backup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186289.aspx

This works for any database engine that I know of. You can perfectly backup up the database, run a script, and restore it. That would make the database be the same way it was before you ran your script.

Way the way, you don't need to put the database offline to do the back up. But the database will be put offline when you do the restore, so be aware of that.

Comment: My worries are about the speed of that process of restoring DB. 
Is it fast enough for DB with size > 30 GB?
Maybe copying those DB files will be enough and safe?

Comment: You won't be able to copy the files unless you deattach the database and then attach it again. The restore is fast but of course it depends on the server. If you have to restore the 30 GB database in a server with 1 core y 2 GB of RAM it will most likely take time. If you are restoring the database on a 16 core with 64 GB ram and a RAID 10 it might take seconds. The database size is not a measure to know performance. If you need to know how long it takes, try doing a restore at a time the business can afford to have the database offline and see how long it takes to run.

Comment: Maybe you can check the following: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/how-to-make-sql-server-backups-and-restores-faster/

Comment: Thank you! I will look on that.

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick script to backup a DB:

```
   SET @fileName = <Backup path> + <Backup file name> + '.BAK'  
   BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName
```